# How do you construct proofs for complex manifolds that in the real case need of partitions of unity?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, holomorphic-functions, complex-manifolds

It is a well-known fact that the partitions of unity are used quite often when dealing with the proof of some technical real-manifold theorem (e.g. Stokes). The advantage of this kind of arguments is that you can reduce your proof to an open subset of the manifold that is dipheomorphic to some $\mathbb{R}^n$ and, in the last instance, you can reduce it to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is "What happens when you are working with a complex manifold and its holomorphic charts?" Is there some mechanism (maybe not so good as partitions of unity) that can "enlighten our job" or it is just about brute strength treatment?

It would be helpful some link or reference to a bibliographical item where some technical proof (it does not matter the theorem dealt) for a complex manifold is developed.

Comment: This question might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924322/how-does-one-create-a-partition-of-unity-for-a-complex-manifold

Comment: I saw it before asking the question, but I think it is not the same. I do know that partitions of unity do not work in this case. My question is about other techniques or methods that can simplify proofs in the complex case (if they exist). If they don't it will be also interesting to see a complete proof of some technical theorem (because I do not see how to proof some theorems directly).